# Food Recipe App on Python using Edamam API won't work

Tags: python, tkinter, edamam-api

Please help. I'm currently new to coding and I can't get a sample program to function. I was following a video about how to create a Recipe Finder Application on Python with the use of Tkinter and Edamam API, but every time I enter a keyword to search in the GUI, It keeps showing errors.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\65978\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\65978\Downloads\recipeApp.py", line 42, in __run_search_query
    recipe = self.__get_recipe(query)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\65978\Downloads\recipeApp.py", line 69, in __get_recipe
    for recipe in query_result:
  File "C:\Users\65978\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py_edamam\__init__.py", line 101, in search_recipe
    yield Recipe(edamam=self, **data)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Recipe.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cuisineType'
```

This is the code :

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from py_edamam import PyEdamam
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser


WINDOW_TITLE = "Recipe App"
RECIPE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 350
RECIPE_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300

class RecipeApp(object):

    def __init__(self, recipe_app_id, recipe_app_key):

        
        self.recipe_app_id = recipe_app_id
        self.recipe_app_key = recipe_app_key
        self.window = tk.Tk()
       
        # Auto resize geometry
        self.window.geometry("")
        self.window.configure(bg="#9ddfd3")
        self.window.title(WINDOW_TITLE)

        self.search_label = tk.Label(self.window, text = "Search Recipe", bg = "#ea86b6")
        self.search_label.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx=5)

        self.search_entry = tk.Entry(master = self.window, width = 40)
        self.search_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx=5, pady = 10)

        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.window, text = "search", highlightbackground = "#ea86b6",
            command = self.__run_search_query)
        self.search_button.grid(column = 2, row = 0, padx = 5)

       
    def __run_search_query(self):

        query = self.search_entry.get()
        recipe = self.__get_recipe(query)

        if recipe:
            recipe_image = recipe.image
            recipe_url = recipe.url
        
        else:
            # Recipe not found
            recipe_image = "https://www.mageworx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Page-Not-Found-13.jpg"
            recipe_url = ""

        self.__show_image(recipe_image)
        self.__get_ingredients(recipe)

        def __open_link():
            webbrowser.open(recipe_url)

        self.recipe_button = tk.Button(self.window, text = "recipe link", highlightbackground = "#ea86b6",
            command = __open_link)
        self.recipe_button.grid(column = 1, row = 7, pady = 10)


    def __get_recipe(self, query):
        edamam_object = PyEdamam(recipes_appid=self.recipe_app_id, recipes_appkey=self.recipe_app_key)
        query_result = edamam_object.search_recipe(query)
        
        # Get first recipe in list
        for recipe in query_result:
            return recipe
    
    def __show_image(self, image_url):
        response = requests.get(image_url)
        
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        img = img.resize((RECIPE_IMAGE_WIDTH, RECIPE_IMAGE_HEIGHT))
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        
        holder = tk.Label(self.window, image = image)
        holder.photo = image
        holder.grid(column=1, row=6, pady=10)
    

    def __get_ingredients(self, recipe):
        ingredients = tk.Text(master = self.window, height = 15, width = 50, bg = "#ffdada")
        ingredients.grid(column=1,row=4, pady = 10)
        ingredients.delete("1.0", tk.END)  

        if recipe == None :
            ingredients.insert(tk.END, "No Recipe found for search criteria")
            return

        ingredients.insert(tk.END, "\n" + recipe.label + "\n")
        for ingredient in recipe.ingredient_names:
            ingredients.insert(tk.END, "\n- " + ingredient)

    def run_app(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
        return
      

# Create App and run the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #API Keys
    APP_ID = "7e13a19a" #Put your app id for edamam api
    APP_KEY = "6261e50464c0c2afb984da19d3bffe51" #Put your app key for edamam api

    recipe_app = RecipeApp(APP_ID, APP_KEY)
    recipe_app.run_app()
```

Comment: That sounds like the data being returned by the Edamam API is including a new field that the py_edamam package does not support, i.e. `cuisineType`.  This should probably be reported as a bug to the py-edamam team.

Comment: Wait.  I have checked their code on github and it shows that their current Recipe class should be able to take cuisineType as a keyword argument.  Are you sure you have the latest py-edamam code?

Comment: Digging further I see that the fix was made back in May, but there is a complaint from 5 days ago that asks that the code update be pushed to the pypi server to be available from pip.  So, you probably have the latest version available from pip, but that version is broken.

Comment: At this point your best bet is to get the latest `py_edamam/__init__.py` file from their git repository (https://github.com/JarbasAl/py_edamam/blob/master/py_edamam/__init__.py) and replace your current `.../site-packages/py_edamam/__init__.py` with it.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, Thanks for your help I'll try it and comment again later about the updates in my code.

Comment: Thank you so much!! for your help it works

Comment: Great.  I have opened an issue on their github page requesting they push the update to PyPI and suggesting that they add a `**kwargs` argument to their `Recipe.__init__` method so that the code won't break like this if/when the Edamam folks add to their data structure.